# What is the most efficient way to pack cylinders in a sphere?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

### Hi, there! I have a weird problem

I was studying solid state physics, the part that was talking about packing atoms in various methods, as well as its efficiency, FCC,BCC,..etc. I read then about sphere stacking and stacking them in a bigger sphere. After all that reading, I am now wondering, how would you stack cylinders in a sphere efficiently.

Given a sphere with radius $R$, and identical cylinders with height $h$ and radius $r$. What is the maximum number of cylinders that could be stacked inside the sphere.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: As much as you want, if one disk can fit in. Disks have zero thickness!

Comment: I have add part of "cylinders with height h" to avoid  someone saying that :D.
I will edit the question
Edit: Here :D @ParclyTaxel

Comment: Interesting question! Is there a reason to suspect the usual way (concentric circles around one diameter of the sphere) would not be best? Also I wonder if there's different strategies depending on values of r and h.

Comment: Getting an explicit formula looks impossible. One obvious general strategy is to form layers of parallel cylinders of thickness $h$ whose cross sections are hexagonally packed, but there are special values of $R$, $r$, and $h$, where this strategy leaves gaps large enough to fit in additional cylinders.