# What algorithm can be used for packing identical cylinders into a rectangular prism in an optimal way in MATLAB?

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, packing-problem

I am trying to fit a maximum number of fixed-size cylinders into a fixed volume and plot them in 3D ([e. g. image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UcXp.png)).

The constraints are the fixed volume, dimensions of the cylinders, the gaps between the cylinders and the gap to the walls.

Comment: This is a hard problem in any language. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4140583/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-pack-cylinders-in-a-sphere

Comment: I have tried this solution in 2D but failed to turn it into 3D

gridSpacing = 2;
rows = 48;
columns = 64;
scalingFactor = sqrt(5) / 2;
xc = 0 : scalingFactor * gridSpacing*2 : columns;
yc = 0 : gridSpacing*2 : rows;

[x, y] = meshgrid(xc, yc);
% Shift every other row by a radius
x(2:2:end, :) = x(2:2:end, :) + gridSpacing;
numCircles = length(x(:));

radii = scalingFactor * gridSpacing * ones(numCircles, 1);
a = viscircles([x(:), y(:)], radii, 'Color', 'r');

pos = [0 0 columns rows];

rectangle('Position',pos,'EdgeColor','b','LineWidth',2.5)

Comment: With all cylinders the same size this isn't quite as hard. Consider packing them vertically as in the picture (essentially circles in a rectangle). Think of the empty space in the box above the cylinders as another box and pack more cylinders there the same way, lying on their sides. This may not be optimal but might well be close, and programmable.